Playing multiple sounds using winsound.Playsound in Python
I am working on a game project in which I want to play sound effects while background music is going on , and I don't want to use any external library. This is my Code :
from winsound import SND_LOOP as LoopMusic,SND_ASYNC as SyncMusic,SND_NOSTOP as NstopMusic,PlaySound

def PlayMusic(num):
    PlaySound(f"Data/Sound/music{num}.wav",LoopMusic|SyncMusic|NstopMusic)

def StopMusic():
    PlaySound(None,SyncMusic)

def PlayEffect(effect):
    PlaySound(f"Data/Sound/Effects/{effect}.wav",SyncMusic)
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    PlayMusic(2)
    PlayEffect("Click")

But this code stops the actual background music played by PlayMusic when the PlayEffect function is called .
I tried using thread module but did not get any output...
